# Best DB for represent a tree structure

Tags: sql, mongodb, graph-databases, database, nosql

Which is the best DB for a tree strucutre?

I have different kinds of objects which can have parent or child objects . The structure of this objects is dinamic, ej: some can have a 'name' field while others dont, some can have a 'menu' field and others an 'image' field.

One element can have 1000 fields(or attributes) while other can have just 1.

An SQL database is discarted, because it can not be schemaless

Currently, I am storing this in mongoDB, but I think it is not the most appropiate thing, because I can not have infinite childs or parents on one document(its limited to 16mb) so I have to make a separate document for every object and then one of the greatest advantaje of mongodb is lost.

Another solution migth be a graph db, im not familiar with them, but they seem the perfect solution, a tree is a graph after all.

So what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A graph database sounds like the right answer.  Please consider looking at [TinkerPop](http://www.tinkerpop.com/) which is an open source graph technology stack.  It enables connection to most any graph database (Neo4j, Titan, OrientDB, Bitsy, etc.) in an agnostic way.  Obviously, that enables you to try out different graph implementations to find the right one for you.

While far from being performant, compared to true graph databases, there's even a [MongoDB implementation](https://github.com/datablend/blueprints-mongodb-graph) of a graph.  I'd recommend starting with a simple in-memory [TinkerGraph and a Gremlin REPL](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Getting-Started) to begin your learning process.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the graph databases. [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) is leading here.